# Kotlin class with generics and implementing interfcae

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-generics

I'm using `Kotlin` in `Android` development and I would like to create class with two generics, one of them `V` must be child class of `View`, and class also should implement some interface `MyInterface`.

How to do that? I've tried something like this

`class Test<T, V>(val value1: String, val map: Map<T, V>) where V: View, MyInterface`

or

`class Test<T, V>(val value1: String, val map: Map<T, V>) where V: View: MyInterface`

but I have no idea what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class Test<T, V: View> (val string: String, val map: Map<T, V>) : MyInterface`

Should be the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that was easier that I expected ;)